# Can I elute my GFP-tagged protein off anti-GFP antibody using a peptide?

Tags: molecular-biology, green-fluorescent-protein

I would like to perform a modified co-immunoprecipitation assay using a GFP-tagged protein.  We are going to bind the tagged protein to anti-GFP antibody then bind that to protein A/G beads, however we want to be able to selectively elute the tagged protein off the beads.  I know that you can elute a FLAG tagged protein off of M2 anti-FLAG antibody by adding excess FLAG, so can I use the same approach with my GFP tag?  If so, does anyone know a commercially available GFP monoclonal antibody who's epitope has been mapped so I can use excess epitope to elute my protein?  Or possibly a source of recombinant GFP?

Answer (score 7):

I found a paper that describes a method to purify GFP fusion proteins using affinity chromatography: ["Purification of GFP fusion proteins with high purity and yield by monoclonal antibody-coupled affinity column chromatography" (1)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18342538). Unfortunately I don't have access to the full text, so I can't check how exactly they elute the GFP fusion protein from the column. They describe a specific monoclonal antibody they use, there should be information on how to obtain it in the paper.

**Abstract:**

> GFP has often been used as a marker of gene expression, protein
>   localization in living and fixed tissues as well as for protein
>   targeting in intact cells and organisms. Monitoring foreign protein
>   expression via GFP fusion is also very appealing for bioprocess
>   applications. Many cells, including bacterial, fungal, plant, insect
>   and mammalian cells, can express recombinant GFP (rGFP) efficiently.
>   Several methods and procedures have been developed to purify the rGFP
>   or recombinant proteins fused with GFP tag. However, most current GFP
>   purification methods are limited by poor yields and low purity. In the
>   current study, we developed an improved purification method, utilizing
>   a FMU-GFP.5 monoclonal antibody (mAb) to GFP together with a
>   mAb-coupled affinity chromatography column. The method resulted in a
>   sample that was highly pure (more than 97% homogeneity) and had a
>   sample yield of about 90%. Moreover, the GFP epitope permitted the
>   isolation of almost all the active recombinant target proteins fused
>   with GFP, directly and easily, from the crude cellular sources. Our
>   data suggests this method is more efficient than any currently
>   available method for purification of GFP protein.

(1) [Zhuang R. et al., Purification of GFP fusion proteins with high purity and yield by monoclonal antibody-coupled affinity column chromatography. *Protein Expr Purif* 2008, **59**(1), 138-43](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18342538)

Comment: In the reported paper the authors used an affinity matrix carrying a covalently coupled mAb. They then eluted the bound proteins using the standard low pH glycine buffer.